# How come function pointers passed to a library (as callback) don't cause segmentation fault when executed?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I recently implemented the functionality of callback registration with a dynamic library using function pointers.
So this means I passed a variable which is located on my local Stack Frame.
How can the library access this variable without crashing for memory access violation?

Comment: The library's code is part of your process' memory too, whether it is statically or dynamically linked.

Comment: So if I have multiple processes using this library, it shares its memory with all of them?

Comment: No, each process gets its own copy of the library in its own virtual address space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a problem because the function itself will never exist on the stack frame.

Suppose you have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void (*fptr)(void);
int num;

void g(void) {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
}

int f(void) {
    int a = 42;
    num = a;

    void (*p)(void) = &g;
    fptr = p;
}

int main(void) {
    f();

    printf("%d\n", num);
    fptr();
}
```

In `f`, we set both `fptr` and `num` to the *value* of a local variable.  If we tried to reference `a` or `p` after `f` returns, we'd have trouble, but we never do.

`fptr` doesn't contain `p`; it contains `&g`, which is just a constant that happens to be where the function `g` is located in memory. And `g` continues to exist at that spot after `f` returns, because the function itself is not a local variable.

And this is what happens when you set up a callback; somewhere in that library is a variable that gets assigned the address of the function you passed.